# How to make a websocket connection globalized

Tags: javascript, angular, rust, websocket

I have a websocket, which receives a message from the client and then sends back the message. When using two browsers, both receive their own messages. But in the server logs, I cannot see both messages.

How can I make it globalized so I can see both messages, is it through creating another websocket which will get these messages and it will send it back?

Frontend:

```js
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebsocketService {
  messages: Array<any> = [];

  chatWebSocket: WebSocket | undefined = undefined;

  createSocket() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.chatWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/ws');
    }
  }
  send(msg: string) {
    console.log(this.chatWebSocket);
    (this.chatWebSocket as unknown as WebSocket).send(msg);
  }
  recv() {
    if (!this.chatWebSocket) return;
    (this.chatWebSocket as WebSocket).addEventListener('message', (e) => {
      this.messages.push(e.data);
    });
  }
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) public platformId: Object) {}
}
```

Server:

```rust
pub async fn chat_ws(
    ws: WebSocketUpgrade,
    user_agent: Option<TypedHeader<UserAgent>>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    if let Some(TypedHeader(user_agent)) = user_agent {
        println!("`{}` connected", user_agent.as_str());
    }

    ws.on_upgrade(handle_chat_socket)
}


pub async fn handle_chat_socket(mut socket: WebSocket) {
    loop {
        if let Some(msg) = socket.recv().await {
            if let Ok(msg) = msg {
                match msg {
                    Message::Text(a) => {
                        socket.send(Message::Text(String::from(a.clone()))).await;
                    },
                    _ => println!("Other"),
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May you share the log please.

Comment: @Jaafar nothing special about the log it just says "client sent: $msg "

Comment: I mean, I can't see the logging code snippet in the server part nor the log. Anyway, please make sure you're not updating your log instead of appending to it.

Comment: @Jaafar It was just a println! which printed into the terminal.